# How to replace bytes \xe3\x80\x80 with byte \x20 in vim?

Tags: vim, substitution

Let's to create target file to operate with.

```
python3
>>> mfile = open("f:/test.txt","wb")
>>> mfile.write(b'\xe3\x80\x80')
3
>>> mfile.close()
```

Now to open  `f:/test.txt`  with `xxd`,you will see three bytes `\xe3\x80\x80` in it,our target file encoding with `utf-8` contains three bytes `\xe3\x80\x80`.

```
python3
b'\xe3\x80\x80'.decode('utf-8')
'\u3000'
```

It means that  the unicode of three bytes in `test.txt` encoding with `utf-8` is `3000`.

```
:s/\%u3000/ /g
```

`s/\%u3000/ /g` can replace bytes `\xe3\x80\x80` with byte `\x20` in vim.

Issue remains still here.

```
:s/\%u3000/\%u20/g 
:s/\%u3000/\%x20/g
:s/\%u3000/\x20/g
```

All the three formats above here can't work,why `\xe3\x80\x80` can be expressed by `\%u3000` in vim, (white blank)  can't be expressed by `\%u20` or `\%x20` or `\x20` ?

can express `\x20`, white blank is printable character,what's more, i want to replace the three bytes  `\xe3\x80\x80` with latin-1's `nbsp`?

The `nbsp` in latin-1 encoding means  Non-breaking space which is NON PRINTABLE CHARACTERS,how to  write the expression in vim?

```
:s/\%u3000/\%ua0/g 
:s/\%u3000/\%xa0/g
:s/\%u3000/\xa0/g
```

None of them can work for the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.How to input non printable characters when to edit a file in vim?

In the insert mode:

```
1.ctrl+v (ctrl+q if ctrl+v call paste from regitor)
2.input u 
3.input the unicode value of non printable characters
4.input enter key
```

2.How to input non printable characters in substitute command of vim's ex mode?

For example, to replace all  bytes `\xe3\x80\x80` with `\xa0`,all byte's encoding is utf-8.

```
1. get the byte's unicode value 

`\xe3\x80\x80`'s unicode value is `3000`,   
`\xa0`'s unicode value is `a0`.

2.press `:` into ex mode.
3.:s/\%u3000/    
4:ctrl+v ua0  
do not input enter as above process
5.go on to input `/g`.
6.press enter.
```

Answer (score 3):

You can type the `\xe3\x80\x80` or `u3000` character by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>u</kbd> and then the 4 Unicode characters, in your case `3000` (check [`:help i_CTRL-V_digit`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-V_digit) ), since is a black character you will see nothing but just a space, you could type `:set list` to see all the places where you have that character or in any case add this to your `.vimrc`

```
set listchars=tab:▸\ ,eol:¬,trail:·,extends:#,nbsp:.
```

Now in the same way you enter the character, you could try to replace it within the command line, but in this case to be available to enter the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> you could try using the command-line window (`:help cedit`).

Go to command mode and after having the `:` press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> it will open the command-line window in where you could go into insert mode and type: `%s/`<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>u</kbd>`3000/ /g` and when done press enter to apply command.

Give a try first before entering the command-line window, since when using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> it may work, not like when using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>  (http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Entering_special_characters)

[image]

In the image instead of replacing with a white space `/ /`, Is replacing with `----` just to visually see the changes.